# Matching id's from two database tables to get username from one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am wanting to match my user_id column from my announcements table to the id column in my users table. I then want to get the username from the users table where the id's match.

I initially had the following query

```
if ($announcements_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM announcements"))
```

I am getting the following error with my current code..

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in
```

Which I know what this means, but do I need to add in every column table from my users table for this to work or is there another way to do this? If I do need to add all of the columns as variables in my bind_result, does it matter which order I put them in? Announcements first or users or vise versa?

```
if ($announcements_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM announcements
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON announcements.user_id = users.id")) {


    $announcements_stmt->execute();
    $announcements_stmt->bind_result($announcements_id, 

$announcements_user_id, $announcements_messages, $announcements_date); 

        if (!$announcements_stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }
        $announcements_stmt->store_result();
         $announcements_result = array();

?>

            Current Announcements
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>   
<?php
        while ($row = $announcements_stmt->fetch()) {
?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                </tr>   

<?php
        } 
?>

    }
```

update..

```
 if ($announcements_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT announcements.id, announcements.user_id, announcements.messages, announcements.date, users.username FROM announcements
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON announcements.user_id = users.id")) {


    $announcements_stmt->execute();
    $announcements_stmt->bind_result($announcements_id, 

$announcements_user_id, $announcements_messages, $announcements_date, $announcements_username); 

        if (!$announcements_stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }
        $announcements_stmt->store_result();
         $announcements_result = array();

?>

            Current Announcements
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>   
    <?php
            while ($row = $announcements_stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_username; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                    </tr>   

    <?php
            } 
    ?>

        }
                </table>
    <?php 
            }           
        }
```

Comment: it looks like you are binding variables where no placeholders exist - there doesn't appear to be a where clause to your sql

Comment: @RamRaider How would I structure this. I'm not entirely sure how to do what you are saying.

Comment: oops - I misread the code - I thought your were binding params but it is actually binding fields for the resultset - sorry. I guess that the recordset will have more than 4 fields though

Comment: I do not have experience in PHP. But, what it looks like that you are binding `$announcements_user_id` and trying to access `$announcements_username`. Are they both same ?

Comment: No, in my announcements table I only have id, user_id, message, date. The username is from the users table. I'm just not sure how to bind the result for that.

Comment: So, the count of result fields does not matches with the count of binding variables. It would be better if you can select only those columns which are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning indicates when you are binding the result fields into variables, the number of variables does not match the number of fields in the result set:

```
$announcements_stmt->bind_result($announcements_id, $announcements_user_id, $announcements_messages, $announcements_date, $announcements_username);
```

The easy way around this is to always specify the fields in the SELECT statement (just an  example):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.messages, t1.date, t2.username
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT *
```

Comment: I have binded the results of everything in my announcements table. I don't know how to bind the result from my users table that I want. The username field.

Comment: Specify `users.username` in the `SELECT` and read the manual on bind_result so you know what you are doing.  The columns and variables have to match up.

Comment: So this? `INNER JOIN users.username
                        ON announcements.user_id = users.id` Then how do I bind that?

Comment: No.. read my answer.  Specify the fields you want after the SELECT.

Comment: Is this closer to what you mean? `SELECT t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.messages, t1.date, t2.username`

Comment: Yes, but you would need to use the table name or alias in place of t1/t2 and need the have the columns/fields match up in the bind_result() arguments.

Comment: Now nothing is even showing up. No errors, just everything is gone. I updated my question.

Comment: Well an update doesn't help, the original issue / warning is gone, now you have a new issue.  Gotta learn this stuff on your own, I can't walk you through everything.